# INNER JOIN Query is not working

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am using INNERJOIN query on two tables naming EMPLOYEE & DEPARTMENT.
There exists a common empID(1234) which is common in both the tables and I want to fetch the data from both tables using join query. BUt its not working. Here is my code below:

```
NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
@"Select EMPLOYEE.* from EMPLOYEE   INNER JOIN  DEPARTMENT ON  EMPLOYEE.empID = DEPARTMENT.empID =%@",_txtfind.text];

        NSLog(@"fetch query is%@",querySQL);

        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,
        query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
             if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
               (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                [resultArray addObject:name];
                NSString *department = [[NSString alloc]   initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                [resultArray addObject:department];
                NSString *year = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:
                (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
                [resultArray addObject:year];
                NSLog(@"result array is %@",resultArray);


            }
           else{
               NSLog(@"Not found");
                    }
            sqlite3_reset(statement);
        }
```

Its always going to else part and displays "Not Found".
Am I doing something wrong? Is my join query is right? I am new to join concept so please help me , your ideas are totally welcome.

Comment: Does the query run in standalone mode in SQLlite?  It is possible that the result set is coming back empty, in which case you will get the `"Not found"` response.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen its give blank when running in sqllite. What Should I do now???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query, which I understand until the end of the `on` clause:

```
Select EMPLOYEE.*
from EMPLOYEE INNER JOIN 
     DEPARTMENT
     ON EMPLOYEE.empID = DEPARTMENT.empID =%@",_txtfind.text];
```

Perhaps you want `where` clause of some sort?

```
Select e.*, d.col1, d.col2, . . .
from EMPLOYEE e INNER JOIN 
     DEPARTMENT d
     ON e.empID = d.empID
where e.empId = 'txtfind.text';  -- something like this
```

In any case, if this doesn't help, then edit your question and show the SQL query after variable substitution.

Comment: But there exists a problem. Data from the second table(DEPARTMENT) is not displaying. Its showing data only from the first(EMPLOYEE) table. I want to display empdesignation which exists in DEPARTMENT table. Any idea how to do that.

Comment: @xxxy2j . . . That is because your sample query has `EMPLOYEE.*`.  If you want columns from `DEPARTMENT`, then you need to also include `d.col1`, `d.col2` and so on (for the appropriate columns).

Comment: Lionoff where should I add these cols. Please modify the query if you can.

Comment: @"Select empName,empdept  from EMPLOYEE  INNER JOIN  DEPARTMENT  ON  EMPLOYEE.empID = DEPARTMENT.empID where EMPLOYEE.empID =%@",_txtfind.text]; I solved the problem using this query. Thnks everyone for ur help